# Summon mobs near player/ Move to player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have this code:

```
/summon spider ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:skeleton,HandItems:[{Count:1,id:bow},{Count:1,id:shield}],ArmorItems:[{Count:1,id:diamond_boots},{Count:1,id:diamond_leggings},{Count:1,id:diamond_chestplate},{Count:1,id:diamond_helmet}],CustomName:Killer,Visible:1,HandDropChances:[1.0f,1.0f],ArmorDropChances:[1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f],ActiveEffects:[{Id:1,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999},{Id:5,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999},{Id:8,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999},{Id:12,Amplifier:0,Duration:999999}]}]}
```

I want the spider riding skeleton to be summoned near a specific player or nearest player or the mobs to go to the player position. I try to use "execute" but it summon the spider only. I play MC version 1.11.2

Sorry if this question was already answered. I searched, but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

The execute command should do the trick. Here is an example that spawns the mob you were trying to spawn at the location of every player.

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ summon spider ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:skeleton,HandItems:[{Count:1,id:bow},{Count:1,id:shield}],ArmorItems:[{Count:1,id:diamond_boots},{Count:1,id:diamond_leggings},{Count:1,id:diamond_chestplate},{Count:1,id:diamond_helmet}],CustomName:Killer,Visible:1,HandDropChances:[1.0f,1.0f],ArmorDropChances:[1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f],ActiveEffects:[{Id:1,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999},{Id:5,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999},{Id:8,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999},{Id:12,Amplifier:0,Duration:999999}]}]}
```

Of course this can be changed to spawn any mob like this:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ summon <your mob> [x] [y] [z] [dataTag]
```

Also, if you wanted to summon it at the location of the nearest player you simply change the @a to @p

Or to do a specific player enter `@a[name=<player name>]`

Comment: It might also be good to use @e for this kind of thing, allowing you to also spawn mobs near other mobs

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute at @a run summon <your mob> ...`

Answer (score 0):

you could do /tp @e @p to tp all mobs to you not sure if that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

The exact command is this command below. The commands before "summon" is for 1.16.x and dont know if it works on 1.11 or not
If you know how 1.11 works you can use this pattern on 1.11 or what version you want:

```
/execute at @billie run summon spider ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:skeleton,HandItems:[{Count:1,id:bow},{Count:1,id:shield}],ArmorItems:[{Count:1,id:diamond_boots},{Count:1,id:diamond_leggings},{Count:1,id:diamond_chestplate},{Count:1,id:diamond_helmet}],CustomName:Killer,Visible:1,HandDropChances:[1.0f,1.0f],ArmorDropChances:[1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f],ActiveEffects:[{Id:1,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999},{Id:5,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999},{Id:8,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999},{Id:12,Amplifier:0,Duration:999999}]}]}
```